# Why does not elt.style.width = undefined work?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

This one beats me every time I am in a hurrry:

```js
elt.style.width = undefined;
```

It does not work (if someone did not know already...).

Then I try:

```js
delete elt.style.width;
```

Just to discover that one does not work either. Then I do the correct version:

```js
elt.style.width = null;
```

It would be much easier to remember if I knew why the first two versions do not work.
Can someone please tell me?

Comment: `delete` should be fairly obvious. Doesn't make sense to try to remove built in element properties especially ones that would affect rendering

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks, good argument. But it is not so obvious since you do not always see the property in for example Chrome Dev Tools. But maybe this was just what I needed. :-)

Comment: `style.width` is a string property. The correct version would be `elt.style.width = ""`.

Comment: @Lain Thanks, but is that exactly the same as removing the property value on the DOM element?

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style#Setting_styles) - _"A style declaration is reset by setting it to `null` or an empty string, e.g., `elt.style.color = null`. Internet Explorer requires setting it to an empty string, and does not do anything when setting it to null."_. Please remember that, although you can manipulate this with JS, it is _not_ just like any other JS object-- these are specific DOM properties, part of an API with a spec that is implemented by browsers-- they expect certain rules to be followed to fit their implementation.

Comment: @Leo: It is the same as removing the property value, if you were using the correct method for it [removeProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/removeProperty). However, removing the property definition itself is a different matter.

Comment: Oh. Setting the value to `""` is by far the most confusing version. I rather forget IE.